# Nuget Package Manager - 2015 - Object not set to reference

Tags: visual-studio

Have been installing packages from Nuget for Google APIs, not something Ive used often but have found after installing the first that the others won't install.

Throws the exception:
"Object Not set to reference of ... " after a bit of toying around found if I delete the packages.config file it will work without a hitch.

Without the file, it doesn't track that I have the component install, but with it won't update to the newest file, so have to delete and reinstall manually?

Question:
Does anyone know how to fix this correctly, each time I install a package the file returns. Not a major, but would be nice to have it run well.